# PHP CURL - BAD REQUEST POST - WHEN POSTFIELDS IS VERY BIG

Tags: php, curl, post

I am sending a POST request with CURL PHP API, when the POSTFIELDS is small there are no problems, but when the POSTFIELDS is very large it responds with error 400 "BAD POST CONTENT".

```
try {

        $header  = array(
            "content-type: application/json",
        );

        $direccionService = $direccion.":".$puerto."/".$direccionService.$operacion;
        // PREPARE THE CURL CALL
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,            $direccionService);
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,         FALSE);
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST,           TRUE);
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     json_encode($dataF));
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        100);
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,     "cookie".$Nit);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        $inf = curl_multi_getcontent($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        $array = array();
        $res = '';
        if ($err) {
            $res = array(
            "error" => "Sintaxis Erronea solicitud",
            "code" => "400",
            "message" => "Curl Error -". $err
            );
        } else {
            $res = $response;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $res = array(
           "error" => "Exception",
           "code" => "406",
           "message" => "Exception -". $e
        );
    }
```

Comment: Your CAPS LOCK is on when it is not supposed to be

Comment: What does this have to do with cURL? This is the response from the endpoint where you are sending the data _to_ - so it has to be fixed on that end as well.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bug. it should not respond `400 Bad Request` when the payload is too large, it should respond [`413 Payload Too Large`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.11). contact the endpoint maintainers and let them know.